# d3.select(this) works on mouseover, but not on function called in mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, this

I am new to javascript and currently struggling with selecting the **this** object while trying to do a d3 selection. I've made the following example, with a function I'm calling, and an on mousemove event:

```
function changeFont() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('font-size', '2em')
}

...
.on('mousemove', function() {
  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  var xVal = mouse[0];

  // this would work, but not when its called in a function
  // d3.select(this)
  //  .attr('font-size', '2em')

  // this works
  d3.select(this)
   .attr("opacity", 1)

  // this doesnt
  changeFont()
});
```

In my main script not shown here, I am organizing my code by writing functions that handle each of the mousemove, mouseover, etc. effects. However because of these functions, I am running into this problem where I can't do *d3.select(this)* inside of that mouseover function... Any thoughts on what I should be doing differently?

Should I pass *this* as a parameter to my changeFont() function? Or should I access *this* in a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your issue 100%, but "this" only has scope in each function.  To use "this" from a parent function in a nested function, assign it to a variable and pass it down.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although Andrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161663/4235784) might be the best fit if you take the question literally, I would like to add my two cents to it. Your real problem does not seem to be to get a hold of `this`, but to repeatedly get access to that element to apply you manipulations. Since fiddling around with `this` can be a pain in JavaScript it might be worth taking a slightly different approach by directly passing the selection instead. This will also improve performance as there is no need to re-select `this` over and over again.

First, let us slightly refactor your `changeFont()` function to accept a selection object.

```
function changeFont(selection) {
  selection
    .attr('font-size', '2em');
}
```

Note, how this makes the function more generally applicable as it does not make any assumptions about the selection passed into it. It could be your `d3.select(this)`, a selection containing multiple elements or any other D3 selection object. Additionally, you do not need to preserve the previous `this` scope.

There are basically two ways of calling this function.

1. The obvious one will directly pass the selection as an argument when calling the function:

   ```
   const d3This = d3.select(this);
   changeFont(d3This);
   ```
2. Fortunately, there is a more elegant way of doing it by resorting to D3's own [`selection.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call) which even allows for method chaining if you need to do multiple calls on the same selection.

   ```
   function changeFont(selection) { selection.attr("font-size", "2em"); }
   function changeFill(selection) { selection.attr("fill", "limegreen"); }
   function changeOpacity(selection) { selection.attr("opacity", "0.1"); }

   // ...
   .on("mouseover", function() {
     // Call the functions for this element.
     d3.select(this)
       .call(changeFont)
       .call(changeFill)
       .call(changeOpacity);

     // Instead, you could also apply the same pattern to all texts.
     d3.selectAll("text")
       .call(changeFont)
       .call(changeFill)
       .call(changeOpacity);

   }
   ```

Comment: Nice, this is a useful pattern that I am surprised I don't see more of.

Comment: Andrew's answer does answer my question more literally, but I think I do like this solution more. This is great thanks for clearing things up!

Answer (score 15):

Just for completeness, since this question has already two very good answers: you can avoid the confusion with `this` if you use the third and second arguments combined. That's something that even D3 developers forget eventually.

In several D3 methods, the current DOM element is just the current index of the nodes' group. So, in the anonymous function...

```
.on("mouseover", function(_, i, n) {
```

... `this` is just `n[i]`, which you can just pass to the other functions. The `_` here corresponds to the first argument, the datum: I'm using `_` just to follow the convention that shows this argument is not used.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can even (for whatever reasons you have) use arrow functions:

```js
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(String)
  .on("mouseover", (_, i, n) => {
    changeFont(n[i])
  });

function changeFont(element) {
  d3.select(element).style("font-size", "2em")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, you can't get the DOM element using `this` inside the arrow function.

Comment: That third argument is too rarely used, to be honest it didn't even cross my mind earlier - nice answer.

Comment: This was a very helpful contribution, thank you!  I'm using d3 in conjunction with Vue and handling "this" can be tricky

Comment: The bit about the arrow function and `this` was SUPER helpful. I had been using an arrow function and could not get it to work. I'm also using d3 v6 so the args in the callback were `event` and `data`, not `data`, `index`, and `elements` like I thought. So changing my arrow function code to `d3.select(event.target)` worked out nicely.

Answer (score 7):

Let's see what `this` is defined as for each of your approaches:

```
// console.log(this) in inline function:
<svg width="960" height="960"> 

// console.log(this) in function called from inline function:
Window → file:///fileName.html
```

`this` is set by how a function is called. D3 conveniently sets `this` to be the DOM element being manipulated by using `.apply` on the function passed to `selection.attr()`, `selection.on()` etc. However, it doesn't do this for functions called within the function passed to `selection.attr()`, `selection.on()`, etc.

We can see that `this` is indeed the DOM element if we log `this` in the function passed to `selection.on()`. If `this` is not explicitly set, it will be the window (unless using strict mode, then it will be undefined). We can see in the nested function, `this` is indeed the window.

Altocumulus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162930/7106086) and Gerardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165216/7106086) avoid  the `this` issue altogether, additionally you could also pass `this` as some regular argument to the function (this pattern is seen in some examples). But if you want to simply be able to copy and paste the code from the inline function to some separately defined function  you can use apply, which will preserve `this` as the element being modified:

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 960)
  .on('mousemove', function() {
     var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
     console.log("inline: ", mouse[0]);
     someFunction.apply(this);
});

function someFunction() {
  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  console.log("not inline: ", mouse[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you needed to pass parameters to your function along with this, you can still use apply:

```
someFunction.apply(this,[parameterA,parameterB,...]);
function someFunction(parameterA,parameterB) { }
```

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 960)
  .on('mousemove', function() {
     var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
     console.log("inline: ", mouse[0]);
     someFunction.apply(this,[mouse[0],mouse[1]]);
});

function someFunction(x,y) {
  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  console.log("not inline: ", mouse[0],x,y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, this inline function calling other functions may just be extra work. If you are *only* calling a function in the inline function, then just pass the called function to `selection.on()` directly, this preserves `this` without any extra steps as d3 will apply the expected value to it (it also still gives you access to the datum and index if needed):

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 960)
  .on('mousemove', someFunction)

function someFunction() {
  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  console.log(mouse[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*Don't place the brackets on the function in this case, we don't want to return the result of the function, we want to use the function itself.*

---

I've use apply (`Function.prototype.apply()`) in my examples, but you can also use call (`Function.prototype.call()`), as Altocumulus notes [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161179/d3-selectthis-works-on-mouseover-but-not-on-function-called-in-mouseover#comment87342506_50161663). The use of call is quite similar. If you aren't passing any parameters to the function and only want to preserve `this`, the usage is the same: `someFunction.apply(this)` / `someFunction.call(this)`. But, if passing parameters, call doesn't use an array for the parameters:

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 960)
  .on('mousemove', function() {
     var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
     someFunction.call(this,mouse[0],mouse[1]); // first parameter will be `this` for someFunction, rest of parameters follow
});

function someFunction(x,y) {
  var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  console.log(mouse[0],x,y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AndrewReid For the sake of completeness it‘s worth mentioning, that you could just as well use `Function.prototype.call` instead of `.apply`.